# Using expand when multiple extensions are present in filename

Tags: command-line

If i'm editing a file, such as

```
/src/test/service.spec.js
```

And I want to echo `service` using `expand`, is there a better way than:

```
:echo expand("%:t:r:r")
```

I want to be able to handle cases where multiple file extensions might be present, and doing `:r:r` seems a bit narrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could try using `split()` to split the filename (`expand('%:t')`) whenever there's a literal dot `\.`. It would return a list whose first item (`[0]`) should be what you are looking for:

```
:echo split(expand('%:t'), '\.')[0]
```